# Cannot deal with some files even as a su: "-rw-r--r--" vs "-rw-r--r-"

Tags: macos, file-permissions, file-attributes

I have a few files that I cannot deal with
(e.g. `head filename` gives me `head: filename: Permission denied`).

`xattr` with these files shows / does nothing.

Here is an example session:

```
vlad@MacBook-03:~/html$ ls *.html | wc -l 
     979

vlad@MacBook-03:~/html$ head -1 *.html > /dev/null
head: 6a69505d39eed3aca809c75519e59c53.html: Permission denied
head: adc6fa4dae0ec2902775fe51806e51aa.html: Permission denied
head: c9f71486e1f27551d99940b460b699f4.html: Permission denied

vlad@MacBook-03:~/html$ echo "As you see, only 3 out of 979 files are 'strange'" 
As you see, only 3 out of 979 files are 'strange'

# Strange access attributes:
vlad@MacBook-03:~/html$ ll | cut -f1 -d" "| sort | uniq -c | sort -n
   1 drwxr-xr-x
   1 drwxrwxrwx
   1 total
   3 -rw-r--r--
 979 -rw-rw-rw-

vlad@MacBook-03:~/html$ ll  6a69505d39eed3aca809c75519e59c53.html
-rw-rw-rw-  1 vlad  staff  42316 Jul 20 03:17:45 2010 6a69505d39eed3aca809c75519e59c53.html


vlad@MacBook-03:~/html$ sudo head 6a69505d39eed3aca809c75519e59c53.html
Password:
head: 6a69505d39eed3aca809c75519e59c53.html: Permission denied
```

Please help. MacOS 10.15.7. Thanks!

Comment: Are you running any kind of antivirus or endpoint protection?

Comment: Do the files have any flags, ACLs, or xattrs (check with e.g. `ls -leO@ 6a69505d39eed3aca809c75519e59c53.html`)? Also, what directory are the files in (some directories have special restrictions besides regular file permissions)?

Comment: If you want help, then just act on one file and detail it and its parent permissions instead of hiding things.

Comment: @Erviw: I had to Google "endpoint protection":). Endpoint protection: no, antivirus: yes, but how on Earth it has to do with not allowing an access to 3 out of 900+ files? 
BTW: The files are all from 2010.

Comment: @Gordon Davidson: 

`ls -leO@ 6c69505d39eed3cbc809b75519e59b53.html 
-rw-rw-rw-  1 vlad  staff  - 42316 Jul 20  2010 6c69505d39eed3cbc809b75519e59b53.html
`

`ls -lartd .
drwxrwxrwx  2 vlad  staff  33490 Jun 28 21:31 .
`
xattr -l 6c69505d39eed3cbc809b75519e59b53.html
# Nothing, no output.
`
Sorry, for some reason I cannot format code either with "`" or with "```".

Comment: @Bib: WHAT am I hiding exactly?!? Please refer to the session I posted in the OP.

Comment: PS: So far, no luck.

Comment: @VladK. We have little idea who owns or what the permissions are of the parent directory, since you've cut them off. We have no idea if this is a local directory or network mounted.